# Using image assets from Cocoapods in Storyboards

Tags: ios, image, storyboard, cocoapods, asset-catalog

I created a Pod with some image assets stored in AssetCatalog. If I try to set one of those images to a UIImageView in storyboard I can select it from the list but it doesn't show when I run the app.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Adam, what do you mean of `Using image assets from Cocoapods in Storyboards`?

Comment: Adam, do you mean you can not use the images under  Pods?

Comment: My Pod contains some images and in my app I try to use them via storyboard, but they won't show.

Comment: It is because is not the main bundle. you should init the bundle with its class.

Comment: I understand I can make it work using code. I interested about can I use these images with storyboard only?